# Passing Database authentication details while starting tomcat

Tags: java, tomcat

I am trying to pass database authentication details dynamically when my Web application deploys into tomcat. This process succeeded when using Windows console, but when porting to Linux and executing `startup.sh`, Tomcat starts the deployed Web Application, but it is not prompting for password.

Comment: Why are you passing database credentials on the command line. I've never heard of anyone doing this before and can't see why it might be a good idea.

Comment: Hi Qwerky actually io dont want to put my database password any where in my code for that i want to pass pasword as commandline argument and  encryption and decryption from at my application end this is actually i want to do it..

Comment: No, this is wrong.  You should not be doing it that way, no matter how much you want to.  Voting to close.

Answer (score 2):

This isn't the way things are usually done.

The proper idiom is to set up a named JNDI connection pool.  It has the credentials and URL at start up; the app server brings it up.  See how to do it [here](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/jndi-datasource-examples-howto.html).

Comment: +1 - or just include the database details as config in the web application you are deploying.